# Word mail merge with Excel data

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

I've got a mail merge document set up in Word 2010. The data I'm using is Excel 2010. I've got some fields at the end of the data that have a lot of text in one cell (more than 255 characters).

Data at the beginning of the file is coming through just fine, but records that appear later do not -- they are cut off mid sentence.

I did find out that Word treats records after a certain point as 'Text'. My question is:

How can I force Word 2010 to treat long fields (from Excel 2010) as 'Memo' and NOT 'Text'?

If I need to set up the MergeFields differently, I can. If I need to format the columns in Excel differently, I can do that as well.

p.s. - I'm currently not using any VBA whatsoever, just a straight mail merge.

Comment: Not really an 'answer', but a work-around: I ended up exporting the Excel file to a tab-delimited file. In Word I referenced the resulting TSV file as my data and it got me the results I needed.

Comment: Alternative workaround: find out what the cut-off point is, then use MID to generate a sequence of smaller fields of that length or less.

Comment: for me it does not work even with CSV/TSV files (I already tried also with the "solutions" of using DDE or filling first 8 rows with data longer than 255 characters, nothing is working). Office 2010.